# Redefinition of virtual operator== in derived class

Tags: c++

I'm about to redefine the operator== on a derived class. The base class has a re-definition of operator== itself, which is:

```
virtual bool operator==(const Dress &c) const {
    return brand==c.brand && size==c.size
}
```

In this case i suppose `brand==c.brand` it's the same as `this.brand==c.brand`.
On my derived class i'm using the same function signature.

```
virtual bool operator==(const Dress &c) const
```

**My questions is:**

Is it correct to check if the type of arguments matches by using

```
typeid(this) == typeid(c)
```

since this redefined function will only be called on derived class' elements?
What i'm not understanding is, how can i redefine the function to return false when called on objects like `derived_class_object == base_class_object` ?

**Base class**

```
class Dress {
private:
    string brand;
    int size;
public:
Dress(string b="unknown", int s=40): brand(b), size(s) {}
virtual bool operator==(const Dress &c) const {
        return brand==c.brand && size==c.size
    }
```

**Derived class**

```
class Tshirt: public Dress {
private:
bool is_shortsleeve;
public:
Tshirt(string b="unknown", int s=40, bool t=true):Capo(b,s),is_shortsleeve(t) {}
virtual bool operator==(const Dress &c) const {

...

}
```

I need to check, beside other controls obviously, that both the elements belong to the derived class. Is it acceptable to do it as i wrote before?

Comment: That depends on how you interpret `operator==` for your class. If `derived` can only ever truly equal another `derived` then you have to test for that. (A counterexample is an ellipse that can be considered equal to a circle, in case both axes of the ellipse are equal to the radius of the circle.)

Comment: Could you pleas add the difference between the base and the derived classes?

Comment: It would be nice to see the declaration of the two classes and how they relate.

Comment: *"I'm about to redefine the operator== on a derived class."* - Stop right there. Your design needs refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class base
{
protected:
    int a;
public:
    base(int a) : a(a) {}
    virtual bool operator == (base & other) const
    {
        return (typeid(*this) == typeid(other)) && this->a == other.a;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived(int a) : base(a)
    {}
    virtual bool operator == (base & other) const
    {
        derived* otherDerived = dynamic_cast<derived*>(&other);
        bool canBeCastToDerived = (0 != otherDerived);
        bool isExactlyTheSameType = (typeid(*this) == typeid(other));
        bool hasOtherProperties = false;

        if (otherDerived)
        {
            hasOtherProperties = (this->a == otherDerived->a);
        }

        return  canBeCastToDerived && isExactlyTheSameType && hasOtherProperties;
    }
};

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    base one(1);
    derived two(2);

    cout << (one == one) << "\n";
    cout << (one == two) << "\n";
    cout << (two == one) << "\n";
    cout << (two == two) << "\n";
}
```

EDIT 1: 
Included all the valid criticism in the comments.

EDIT 2:
Changed example to explicitly include other variations.

Comment: I am not familar with `typeid()` but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) seems to indicate that only the `type_index(typeid)` is guaranteed to be equal, not necessarily the typeids proper.

Comment: Yes, but what happens when using the same signature as the base class? What changes in the code if you use both `virtual bool operator == (const base & other) const` instead of using non virtual redefinition on derived class?

Comment: You are not overriding `operator==` here. You changed its signature.

Comment: If you compare a `derived` as first argument and a `base` as second, the `operator==` is not found

Comment: Also, `typeid(this) == typeid(other)`should always fail (other is a reference). It probably must be `typeid(*this) == typeid(other)`, doesn't it? Or possibly `typeid(this) == typeid(&other)`

Comment: You are still comparing typeids directly, which are not guaranteed to compare equal even for the same types. You must use the type_index. (Or, perhaps better, follow @Gerstrong's suggestion to try a dynamic cast.)

Comment: Thanks guys, now i got it !

Answer (score 3):

First of all RunTimeTypeInformation (RTTI) should be enabled. Then you could use `dynamic_cast<Derived*>` and see if you get a valid pointer to the object. If the object was built with `Derived` it would return a valid pointer otherwise `nullptr` and you know it is something else. Of course you can retry that with `dynamic_cast<Base*>`.

typeid() will also work but with `typeid(*this) == typeid(c)`

Comment: Thanks Gerstrong! So beside the dynamic cast, i can still use typeid, but `this` is a pointer to the first operand and not a reference to it, so that's why you are using it dereferenced. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the case. Compare the objects, references or pointers but not in mixed form.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the `this` and `c` has different type, so the check you need is

```
typeid(*this) == typeid(c)
```

Comment: So `this` keyword in this case is a pointer to the first operator in operator==, and not a reference to the operator itself, right?